# Drupal 7 dompdf no dat in foreach loop

Tags: php, drupal

I try to send an email that has as attachment a pdf created with dompdf.
I have created a function to send one by one and another to send them all at once.
The problem is that at the function to send them all at once, the attachments do not have any data from database.

Below is my function code:

```
function cust_finance_send_invoice_callback(&$context){
  $batch_limit = 10;
  global $language;

  if (empty($context['sandbox'])) {
    $query_rs = db_select("my_invoices", "i");
    $query_rs->join("node", "n", "i.nid = n.nid");
    $query_rs->join("field_email_invoice", "e", "n.nid = e.entity_id AND e.entity_type = 'node'");
    $query_rs->fields("i", array("nid"));
    $query_rs->condition("i.sent", 0, "=");
    $query_rs->condition("e.field_email_invoice", "", "!=");
    $query_rs->condition("e.bundle", "page", "=");
    $total_results = $query_rs->countQuery()->execute()->fetchField();

    $context['sandbox']['progress'] = 0;
    $context['sandbox']['max'] = $total_results;
  }
  if( !is_array($context["results"]) ) {
    $context["results"] = array();
  }

  if ( $context['sandbox']['max'] > 0 ) {
    $invoices_rs = db_select("finance_invoices", "i");
    $invoices_rs->join("node", "n", "i.nid = n.nid");
    $invoices_rs->join("field_email_invoice", "e", "n.nid = e.entity_id AND e.entity_type = 'node'");
    $invoices_rs->fields("i", array("id", "nid"));
    $invoices_rs->fields("n", array("title"));
    $invoices_rs->fields("e", array("field_email_invoice"));
    $invoices_rs->condition("i.sent", 0, "=");
    $invoices_rs->condition("e.field_email_invoice", "", "!=");
    $invoices_rs->condition("e.bundle", "prd", "=");
    $invoices_rs->orderBy("i.id", "desc");
    $invoices_rs->range(0, $batch_limit);
    $invoices = $invoices_rs->execute()->fetchAll();

    foreach( $invoices as $invoice ) {
      $txn = db_transaction();
      try {
        $send_invoice_id = db_update("my_invoices")->condition("id", $invoice->id)->fields(array("sent" => 1))->execute();

        $context['results'][] = $invoice->title;
        $context['message'] = t("Sent invoices so far: @nr_invoices.", array("@nr_invoices" => count($context['results'])) );
        $context['message'] .= "<br />" . t("Last sent invoice was to @someone", array("@someone" => $invoice->title) );

        $params = array(
          "subject" => variable_get("cust_mail_invoice_generated_sent_title", "My subject"),
          "body" => variable_get("cust_mail_invoice_generated_sent_body", t("Body with the link: \n\n[invoice_link].\n\nThanks,\nTest Team")),
          "to" => "my-email@hotmail.com"
        );
        $salt = "fsdfsdge4456546467"; //test salt
        $hash = md5($invoice->nid . $invoice->id . $salt);
        $invoice_link = " " . url("node/" . $invoice->nid . "/finance/pdf/" . $invoice->id . "/" . $hash, array("absolute" => true)) . " ";
        $params["body"] = str_replace("[invoice_link]", $invoice_link, $params["body"]);
        $prd = node_load($invoice->nid);
        if ($dompdf = cust_finance_render_invoice_pdf($prd, $invoice)) {
          $params['attachment'] = array('filename' => "invoice-$invoice->id.pdf", 'filecontent' => $dompdf->output(), 'filemime' => 'application/pdf');
        }
        drupal_mail("cust_function", "cust_function_invoice_generated_sent_mail", $params["to"], $language, $params);
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        $txn->rollback();
        $context['message'] = t("Sent invoices so far: @nr_invoices.", array("@nr_invoices" => count($context['results'])) );
        $context['message'] .= "<br />" . t("Last processed item: Failed to send invoice to @someone", array("@someone" => $invoice->title) );
      }
      $context['sandbox']['progress']++;
    }
    if ($context['sandbox']['progress'] != $context['sandbox']['max']) {
      $context['finished'] = $context['sandbox']['progress'] / $context['sandbox']['max'];
    } else {
      $context['finished'] = 1;
    }
  } else {
    $context['finished'] = 1;
  }
}
```